# Подсчёт исходящего трафика

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Мне необходимо на сайте реализовать подсчёт всего исходящего трафика. То есть: при каждой загрузке любого файла (у меня все файлы - это `php`-скрипты) в файл записывается сумма всего трафика, который там был записан и нового трафика (размер страниц меняется при каждом обновлении). Вопрос: как реализовать это (захват объёма общего трафика) средствами `PHP`?

Comment: Точно средствами PHP это измерить не получится.  Примерно можно сделать так:  
1. Посмотреть какая длина у HTTP заголовков отдаваемых сервером средняя.  
2. Включить буферизацию в PHP.  
3. Перед выдачей страницы посмотреть длину текста в буфере и сложить ее с средней длиной заголовков.  
4. Сохранить данные куда требуется и отдать страницу.

Comment: Если честно, не очень понял, что тут написано... Видите ли, мне всего 14 лет... У меня на бесплатном хостинге ограниченный исходящий трафик (1 ГБ/мес), и когда лимит заканчивается, он выдаёт ошибку, причём не в самой лучшей форме. Мне нужно сделать подсчёт трафика, чтобы когда лимит подходит к концу (примерно за 2 мб - страницы маленькие) выдавать приличное предупреждение.

Comment: Не в самой лучшей форме- это матом что ли ?

Comment: Анализировать логи HTTP сервера.

Comment: Хмм... мне бы какое-то готовое решение... а где логи лежат, а уж тем более - как из них трафик извлечь - понятия не имею :)
Может, есть что-то из области CGI? ещё не учил, но попробую разобраться...

Comment: Не в самой лучшей форме- это матом что ли ?
ну, почти:)
самым грубым, на который только способен стандартный вариант апача с лимитизированным исходящим трафиком.

Comment: @k1-801: вы можете где-то смотреть в том хостинге, сколько на данный момент трафика израсходовано / осталось? Наверное, реальнее всего написать скрипт, который будет туда залезать периодически.

Comment: вы можете где-то смотреть в том хостинге, сколько на данный момент трафика израсходовано / осталось?

Посмотрел, есть такое дело... но не знаю, как это оттуда извлечь.
К слову, если кому интересно - хостинг http://hostinger.ru (это не реклама хостинга, просто адрес чтоб посмотрели что и как достать оттуда).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готовое решение вряд ли кто-то станет писать для Вас.

Направления три:

1. как предложил [@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus) буферизировать тело ответа (html код страницы), считать его объём, прибавлять средний "вес" заголовков, и таким образом получать трафик;
2. написать парсер, который будет автоматически заходить на нужную страницу хостинга под Вашим паролем, чтобы получить состояние расхода трафика. И например, отправлять Вам на почту предупреждение, когда более 90% израсходовано, или выключать сайт, «дёрнув» некую секретную ссылку;
3. Поднять правую руку повыше, задержаться на секунду, и потом резко махнуть вниз: «а, фиг с ним..». Гигабайт трафика в месяц это довольно много, и если только Вы не популярную соц. сеть развернули на бесплатном хостинге, хватит с запасом.